# Setting a static object for use across multiple projects

Tags: xml, vb.net, object, global

I need a sanity check on my approach to a "global" object...

I have a dictionary in xml format that I wish to share across multiple projects running in the same main application, but I need to insure that if the xml is modified (new entry, etc) that this information is updated across any other project dll which is currently accessing the dictionary.

(Note - I'm using the term "dictionary" in NON-programming terms)

I'm assuming the best approach would be to create a dll with static methods that loads the xml and then updates as necessary, but how would I keep from repeatedly having to load the xml file on each call?

For example, my main form displays a listview of vocabulary items. Clicking on an item launches a "dictionary editor" which is a separate project dll. Any changes here need to be reflected on the main form.

Currently I'm opening the xml file from the main screen and then passing the XML by reference to any other form being displayed (these are dlls), it works, but I don't think that's the right way to go about it.

Ultimately I want the user to be able to right click on a word and be able to access the dictionary entry and ALSO be able to edit it, i.e. add a new definition. Meanwhile if the vocabulary entry is on screen anywhere else, it needs to be updated.

I suppose what I am trying to do is the equivalent of having global database connection, but with xml rather than SQL Server.

(Maybe an even simpler question - "can I create a global xml object across projects?")

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use a single library project to load the data and have every other project access it from there then you simply use an `If` statement to ensure that you get it only once. That might look like this:

```vb
Private Shared _data As Object

Public Shared ReadOnly Property Data As Object
    Get
        If _data Is Nothing Then
            'Get data here.
            _data = New Object
        End If

        Return _data
    End Get
End Property
```

or like this:

```vb
Private Shared _data As New List(Of Object)
Private Shared _isDataInitialised As Boolean = False

Public Shared ReadOnly Property Data As List(Of Object)
    Get
        If Not _isDataInitialised Then
            'Get data here.
            _data.Add(New Object)

            _isDataInitialised = True
        End If

        Return _data
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this will keep the different project's shared Object up to date - just by using the "Shared" attribute in the Declaration for the object?

I'll experiment...should be easy to test...

(I'm basically already using the same code as you suggest, but without the "Shared")

Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCarp, the `Shared` keyword declares a member of the type, rather than of instances of the type. With that code in a class declared in a library, every other assembly that accesses that type in that library will be seeing the same value. The first time the property is accessed, the `If` condition is `True` and the field gets set. On subsequent property accesses, the `If` condition is `False` and the existing value is used. Very common and simple stuff. Because there's only one object, any changes made to that object from any of the assemblies accessing will be seen everywhere.

Comment: Keyword "simple stuff"
 :)
 I've been out of programming for about a decade, so thank you for the explanation...trying things out now...

Answer (score 0):

You guys lead me to a solution which appears to accomplish the task.

Took me while to wrap my head around it using a Singleton (although there appears to be some aversion by some to use this approach):

I put the following in each class DLL:

Public objSingle as TheDLL.TheClassObject

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property GetInstance As TheClassObject
    Get
        Static INST As TheClassObject= New TheClassObject
        objSingle = INST
        Return INST
    End Get
End Property
```

In each form -

objUniversal = TheVariousDllClasses.TheClassObject.GetInstance

Thanks.